# Get files from sub directory using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, file, datagrid, directory

I have a directorry which contains many folders such as **`folder1,folder2,folder3`** etc..which contains sub-directories..In that I have a folder name **`"special"`** which contains some files

Now I would like to get all those files based on the name of the sub-directory

Example:

```
C:\Users\desktop\Myfolder\folder1\special\
C:\Users\desktop\Myfolder\folder2\special\
C:\Users\desktop\Myfolder\folder3\special\
C:\Users\desktop\Myfolder\folder4\special\
```

Now I need to get all the files from each special folder of all the folder1,folder2,folder3 and folder4 and display them in gridview.

Comment: `based on the name of the sub-directory` Are you trying to fetch the files in certain order.?

Comment: nothing like that...sub-directory in the sense the foldername with special.

Answer (score 0):

if your datagridview is datagridview1 and countains two columns and you want to add the name file and last modified here is the solution ..

```
    For Each sDir In Directory.GetDirectories("C:\Users\desktop\Myfolder\", "special", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        For Each File In Directory.GetFiles(sDir)
            Dim detailedfile As New IO.FileInfo(File)
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(detailedfile.Name, detailedfile.LastAccessTime)
        Next
```

next

if you want to add more details in the gridview you have just to add more `columns` and more integers in `the DataGridView1.Rows.Add`

Comment: can you tell me how to add the filenames to the gridview ?

Answer (score 0):

I just worked on your case, and i think the following piece of code will suits your requirement. The given code will drill through the directories and it display the filenames if it is comes under the `special` directory. Comment me back if i wrongly answered your question.

The procedure,

```
Private Sub GetFiles(ByVal xPath As String)

        Try

            If Directory.GetDirectories(xPath).Length > 0 Then
                For Each xDir As String In Directory.GetDirectories(xPath)
                    If Directory.Exists(xDir) Then
                        GetFiles(xDir)
                    End If
                Next
            End If

            If Directory.GetFiles(xPath).Length > 0 Then
                For Each xDir As String In Directory.GetFiles(xPath)
                    If UCase(Path.GetDirectoryName(xDir)).EndsWith("SPECIAL") Then
                        MsgBox(Path.GetFileName(xDir))
                    End If
                Next
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub
```

and the call,

```
 call GetFiles("D:\test")
```

Comment: @K3rnel31 Though, I feel satisfied while working with nuts and bolts.

Answer (score 0):

```
grid1.DataSource = (From p1 In IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\Users\desktop\Myfolder\", "*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                    Where p1.Contains("\special\"))

grid1.DataBind()
```